# Как зафиксировать элемент в нижней центральной части экрана на мобильном устройстве?

Tags: css

Всем привет.
Как сделать так, чтобы некий  с контентом ВСЕГДА был прижат к нижней части экрана НА МОБИЛЬНОМ УСТРОЙСТВЕ и при этом НЕ МЕНЯЛ свои размеры и местоположение ни при увеличении масштаба на экране (разведение двумя пальцами), ни при при прокрутках (как горизонтальных, так и вертикальных) страниц сайта в мобильном браузере.
Реально ли в этом случае обойтись одними только средствами CSS?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А что вы уже пробовали делать? Покажите простой пример.

Comment: Посмотрите: call.emagame.ru

Comment: Вас просят показать код, который вы уже написали. Тут не принято просто спрашивать как - тут принято показывать код, который вы написали и спрашивать почему этот код не работает (что я не допонимаю)

Comment: Не, все ок, по адресу и есть простой рабочий пример с телефонной кнопкой, которую нужно зафиксировать при зуме (pinch to zoom).

Comment: Вообще, насколько я понимаю, CSS тут не обойтись. Нужно скриптом считать, насколько и куда страницу приблизили и трансформировать кнопку соответственно. Кстати, position fixed + css transforms зачастую сделают вашу кнопку нерабочей (тач на ней не будет регистрироваться).

Comment: Т.е. одним CSS тут не обойтись, я правильно понимаю? 
Вы предполагаете, что каждый раз при прокрутке или изменении масштаба страницы, скрипт должен перерисовывать кнопку заново, отрисовывая её изначально заданный размер?

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
```

Comment: Это + запрет на зум пальцами <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>

Comment: @SergeySnegirev Зачем запрещать маштабирование - элемент будет всегда 100% вне зависимости от того как увеличена страница.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 
Увы, такой вариант не годится, потому что при зуме или прокручивании страницы блок уходит из зоны видимости.

Comment: @Равиль вы что то делаете не так - блок не может уходить из зоны видимости при прокрутке в принцыпе - может быть стоит добавить z-index:5555; , если у вас блок уходит, значит у вас ошибка, вероятно этот div, css код которого я предоставил у вас вставлен в другой div. А должен идти самым последними не быть потомком других дивов

Comment: @ГошкаТарасов В мобильной версии при зуме и прокручивании при зуме блок не видно. Видимо, Сергей Снегирёв прав, нужно js какой-нить прикручивать, чтобы отрисовывать форму каждый раз. Хотя и странно, мне казалось, что можно и силами CSS решить этот вопрос.
=)